# In how many ways can three employees be selected to be leaders if two of them must be mathematicians?

Tags: probability

The research and development department for a computer manufacturer has 
26 employees: 8 mathematicians, 12 computer scientists, and 6 electrical 
engineers. They need to select three employees to be leaders of the 
group. In how many ways can they do this if two of them must be 
mathematicians?

Applying combinations I believe the solution should be $\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{18}{1}=504$

Could $\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{18}{1}+\dbinom{8}{3}$ be also correct? If not why?

Answer (score 1):

Your second answer is correct.

You can have exactly two mathematicians and exactly one non-mathematician, or you can have three mathematicians.

There are:

$$\dbinom{8}{2}\dbinom{26-8}{1}+\dbinom{8}{3} = 560$$

ways to choose the leaders.

Comment: The answer from the textbook is 504. I suppose they missed something too.

Comment: If they add one word to the problem: "exactly", their answer becomes correct. If they were to ask in how many ways "exactly" two of the leaders are mathematicians, then the answer is 504.

Comment: I see it looks ambiguous as it it, I agree with you, but usually books use "at least" to specify the possibility of both 2 and 3. In this case, without knowing the answer, I'd go myself for exactly two.

Comment: You are told two must be mathematicians. You are given no indications about the third one. Why would you assume that third one must not be a mathematician? Typically, when counting "ways" you are not making assumptions that are not directly written into the problem. I am not saying you are wrong, but I tend to err on the side of not adding my own assumptions.

Comment: I would suggest that this answer is marked as accepted. Here is a simulation in R confirming the result: `math = letters[1:8]; others = 1:18; combo = c(math, others); nsim = 10^5; mat = matrix(0,nsim,3); for(i in 1:nsim){z = sort(sample(combo[1:8],2,0)); mat[i,] <- sort(c(z,sample(combo[-which(combo %in% z)],1,0)))};nrow(unique(mat))`.